# Error when using spell-checker in Portuguese

Tags: flyspell, ispell, spell-checking

I wrote a text file in Portuguese. I have changed my dictionary to `portugues`. I tried to `spell-check buffer` and I get the following error message:

```
Starting new Ispell process aspell with portugues dictionary...
ispell-init-process: Error: Expected language "pt_PT" but got "en".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you change the dictionary to Portuguese ? You'd need something like this :

(setq ispell-program-name "/usr/bin/hunspell")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "pt_BR")
(flyspell-mode 1)

And also install the Portuguese dictionary for hunspell.

This is assuming Linux, Brazilian Portuguese, and hunspell as your preferred program. If anything is different, you'd have to chamber that or provide details here.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot I had solved this problem before with this code in init.el: ```;; Portuguese dictionary
(with-eval-after-load "ispell"
  (setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
  (setq ispell-dictionary "en_GB,en_US,pt_PT")
  ;; ispell-set-spellchecker-params has to be called
  ;; before ispell-hunspell-add-multi-dic will work
  (ispell-set-spellchecker-params)
  (ispell-hunspell-add-multi-dic "en_GB,en_US,pt_PT"))```

Answer (score 0):

This message is shown when Emacs is trying to get the version of your `aspell` by doing

```
aspell -a -m
```

(in `ispell-start-process`).

What this message is trying to tell you is that your personal dictionary is expected to be for the languare `pt_PT`, but it has `en` in its top row.

The personal dictionaries are named as

```
~/.aspell.LANG_NAME.prepl
~/.aspell.LANG_NAME.pws
```

On windows, depending on your config, this `~` may mean `%HOME%`, `%APPDATA%` or `cygwin`’s `/home/USERNAME`.  I think fixing the top line should deal with it.